# Pivot_longer: GVCF columns into rows

Tags: r, pivot, data-wrangling, genetics, vcf-variant-call-format

Good afternoon,

after browsing stack overflow and not finding a solution to my particular problem I decided to ask the community hoping this could be helpful to someone else as well.

I have genetic data on a joint VCF format. I am trying to convert multiple columns into just two which encapsulate name of sample and genotype info respectively. It is quite a big dataset so I am trying to set a function or for loop that allows me to do so.

here is a mockup of the data format I am working with

```
df <- structure(list(Chromosome = c("chr 1", "chr 2", "chr 3", 
"chr 4", "chr 5", "chr 6"), position = c("123444", 
"364829", "098090", "123134", "123234", 
"34234"), reference = c("C", "G", 
"C,GC", "ATTA", "GATTACA", "TC,GCT"
), alt = c("AC,G", "CG.GT", "A,*", 
"GA,CGT", "TA,GTA", "AAC"), 
AD_GT_SAMP_1 = c('0,0|./.|', '148,136|0/1|', '148,132|0/1|', '48,236|1/1|', '0,0|./.|','0,0|./.|'),
V5 = c('zw42dx28.cd14.20180120.ef','zw42dx28.cd14.20180120.ef','zw42dx28.cd14.20180120.ef','zw42dx28.cd14.20180120.ef','zw42dx28.cd14.20180120.ef','zw42dx28.cd14.20180120.ef'),
AD_GT_SAMP_2 = c('0,10|./.|', '148,136|0/1|', '148,132|0/1|', '428,236|1/1|', '10,0|./.|','20,0|./.|'),
V7 = c('xs82d2x8.bulk.20180121.ef','xs82d2x8.bulk.20180121.ef','xs82d2x8.bulk.20180121.ef','xs82d2x8.bulk.20180121.ef','xs82d2x8.bulk.20180121.ef','xs82d2x8.bulk.20180121.ef'))) %>%
as.data.frame()
```

Columns 1:4 are constant for all samples. I would like column 5 to have all sample names currently stored in (data[,c(5,7,9,...)])and column 6 to have their genotype info currently stored in(data[,c(6,8,10,...)])

I have tried using pivot_longer and while it does not give me an error when I attempt:

```
pivot_longer(data = mock_gvcf, cols = c(V5,V7,etc...), names_to = '.value')
```

The dataset shifts the columns all the way to the right (e.g. In a dataset with 80 columns where v5-v7-v9-v11... hold the names of samples, the columns do not change in content but get shifted to the right of column v80).

Edit: The comments below help tidy the data efficiently for the mock data. However, it seems that the name format in the real dataset is the problem.

The samp_id format for real data is in the form : (sampid.celltype.collectiondate.stageofcollection)
Where sampid has 4 different names
celltype has 4 different types
Collection date has 6 timepoints
and stage of collection has 3 timepoints

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the code the column names are specified as V5, V7, V9, but in dput, the names are different

Comment: Yes, correct. I took the last part from the actual dataset where columns are named V# . in the mock DF case, they would be SAMP_1_NAME and SAMP_2_NAME

Comment: when you say dataset does not change.  Have you assign it to an object i.e. `mock_gcf1 <- pivot_longer(data = mock_gvcf, cols = c(V5,V7,V9), names_to = '.value')` and check `mock_gcf1`

Comment: yes, the number of columns remains the same but it sends them to the end of the data frame. So columns V5-V7-V9 are at the end to the right (e.g 80 columns, V5-V7-V9 are now to the right of V80).

Comment: It would be great if you can update your post with the expecetd output based on the example you showed

Answer (score 1):

```
pivot_longer(df, -(1:4),  names_to = c('.value', 'grp'), names_pattern = '(.*)_(\\d+)')

# A tibble: 12 x 7
   Chromosome position reference alt    grp   AD_GT_SAMP   sAMP      
   <chr>      <chr>    <chr>     <chr>  <chr> <chr>        <chr>     
 1 chr 1      123444   C         AC,G   1     0,0|./.|     SAMP1_NAME
 2 chr 1      123444   C         AC,G   2     0,10|./.|    SAMP2_NAME
 3 chr 2      364829   G         CG.GT  1     148,136|0/1| SAMP1_NAME
 4 chr 2      364829   G         CG.GT  2     148,136|0/1| SAMP2_NAME
 5 chr 3      098090   C,GC      A,*    1     148,132|0/1| SAMP1_NAME
 6 chr 3      098090   C,GC      A,*    2     148,132|0/1| SAMP2_NAME
 7 chr 4      123134   ATTA      GA,CGT 1     48,236|1/1|  SAMP1_NAME
 8 chr 4      123134   ATTA      GA,CGT 2     428,236|1/1| SAMP2_NAME
 9 chr 5      123234   GATTACA   TA,GTA 1     0,0|./.|     SAMP1_NAME
10 chr 5      123234   GATTACA   TA,GTA 2     10,0|./.|    SAMP2_NAME
11 chr 6      34234    TC,GCT    AAC    1     0,0|./.|     SAMP1_NAME
12 chr 6      34234    TC,GCT    AAC    2     20,0|./.|    SAMP2_NAME
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I changed the pattern of the names as the real dataset has a name format of (sample.celltype.collectiondate.caseorcontrol) I am however getting : Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL 
Do you know why that is?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by changing the pattern of names? do you mean the `names_pattern` argument?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.  Names have four elements to them in my data ((sample.celltype.collectiondate.caseorcontrol)

Comment: @SebastianGM you cannot change that argument. Use it the way I  wrote it

Comment: what would you recommend doing for the real dataset? your suggestion works well for the mock dataset but not for the real data. The name pattern is different for that one, on the (sample.celltype.collectiondate.caseorcontrol) format vs SAMP#_NAME

Comment: @SebastianGM I see what you mean.  could you paste 5 column names here. In that case I can look at the vector ad see the pattern

Comment: @SebastianGM So which columns do you want to join together?

Comment: I'd like to join together all Samp_id columns (With the 4 parts to it) so that all samples names are stored in one column, and that their respective genotypes (AD_GT_SAMP in the case of the mock data)is stored in another column. 

I don't want to break the name apart at this stage, I will do so later and create variables for that as well.

Comment: @SebastianGM just update the dataset with the correct column names

Comment: @SebastianGM you have not. The data given in the example still contains previously given names. Do not edit the question. Just edit the dataset. ie ensure that the dataset contains the names similar to those in the original dataset

Comment: Please let me know if changes still do not appear. I have now changed names and variable names

Comment: @Onyambu I deleted my post.  I think our answers are almost same :=) although I didn't see yours while answering

Comment: @akrun they were different. Also it seems we might not be able to help the OP since they are using different names in the mock data vs the original data

Comment: Can't thank you two enough for taking the time to help me. I updated the names to match the format of the original data. Any input regarding that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @SebastianGM Not really you now have `v5` ,`v7` I really doubt there is a column names `v5` in your original data. Your edit seems to be the expected output rather than the  original dataset.

Comment: @Onyambu unfortunately that is what the names are

Comment: @SebastianGM you mean `v5` and `v7` are the names or `'zw42dx28.cd14.20180120.ef','zw42dx28.cd14.20180120.ef'` are the names??

Comment: The actual sample names are 'zw42dx28.cd14.20180120.ef','zw42dx28.cd14.20180120.ef'. But the column names in the dataset appear as V5, V7. There is no header and using the first sample as a header would not work due to the values in some of the other columns

Comment: @SebastianGM you could have said that from the beginning. Okay.   you can try  using `names_pattern = '(\\D+)(\\d+)'`

Comment: My apologies, still learning how to use Stack Overflow. I get Error: `regex` should define 1 groups; found.

Comment: @SebastianGM sorry I am unable to help. That is because the data given is not a good representation of the data you have. You may consider asking the question again. This time round  probably paste the output of `dput(head(your_data)[, 1:8])`